# Evaulation of a Topology Proof

Tags: general-topology, solution-verification

I have been using Munkres' Topology in my Topology class and we have been going over homework exercises. One of my classmates submitted a pretty sizable proof to a question, but mine was only a few lines. I am now uncertain whether or not I made some mistake in my proof. The question and my solution are included below.

Chapter 31 Exercise 5: Let $f, g : X \to Y$ be continuous: assume that $Y$ is Hausdorff. Show that $\{x | f(x) = g(x)\}$ is closed in $X$.

Proof: Note that $S = X - \{x | f(x) = g(x)\} = \{x | f(x) \neq g(x)\}$. Clearly $S$ is open in $X$ as the arbitary union of elements in $X$. Hence $\{x | f(x) = g(x)\}$ is closed in $X$.

Did I make a major mistake in this proof?

Comment: Why "clearly" $S$ is open in $X$?

Comment: The purpose of this exercise is precisely to show what you call "clearly".

Comment: The word "clearly" never belongs in a homework assignment. If it is so clear, then write the justification. Indeed, "clearly" rarely belongs in a textbook either, and it is used far too often in my opinion.

Comment: @trevorK very true, I find myself saying "clearly" far too often instead of providing justification...I didn't even notice doing it above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just sort of stated that you were done, without providing much justification.

My answer had an error in it.  The condition $\{x:f(x)=g(x)\}$ is closed is in fact *equivalent* to $Y$ being Hausdorff.  See @HennoBrandsma's response.

Comment: Apologies if I'm missing something obvious – the codomain of $f$ and $g$ is an arbitrary Hausdorff space $Y$, and not a topological group or something similar, so it's not clear what your definition of $h$ should mean in general.

Comment: Good point.  I will have to try to adjust. @diracdeltafunk

Comment: Is it true that the preimage of a closed set under a continuous function must be a closed set?

Comment: Yes, and the proof of this fact really is ~3 lines! You should probably try to work it out using the definitions of continuous and closed.

Comment: @diracdeltafunk couldn't we just have $h: X \to Y$ defined by $h(x) = f(x) - g(x)$? Is this a sufficient domain and codomain?

Comment: What does it mean to subtract two elements of $Y$? This is the issue with the definition – Hausdorff spaces don't come with a notion of subtraction.

Comment: You cannot just use $T_1$-ness, if $X$ is $T_1$ but not $T_2$, then the identity on $X$ is a counterexample (an infinite set in the cofinite topology will do). So you need $T_2$!

Comment: @HennoBrandsma Then my solution is incorrect.

Comment: $X$ wasn't required to be anything.  I don't see what's wrong with my solution.  And I don't understand your counterexample. @HennoBrandsma

Comment: @ChrisCuster the diagonal is closed iff a space is Hausdorff.

Comment: @HennoBrandsma yes, I remember that.  So there's a mistake.

Answer (score 2):

A slick solution: $\Delta_Y=\{(y,y): y \in Y\}$ is closed in $Y^2$ iff $Y$ is Hausdorff. And so if $Y$ is Hausdorff $\{x: f(x)=g(x)\}=(f \nabla g)^{-1}[\Delta_Y]$ is closed in $X$, where $f\nabla g: X \to Y^2$ is the map that sends $x$ to $(f(x),g(x)) \in Y^2$ and which is continuous when $f$ and $g$ are.

If we weaken $Y$ to $T_1$ we don't have this conclusion: Let $X=\Bbb Z$ in the cofinite topology and let $Y=X$, which is $T_1$ but not Hausdorff. Then for the continuous $f(n)=n$ and $g(n)=|n|$ (the preimage of a finite set is finite, so continuity follows) we have that $\{x: f(x)=g(x)\}= \Bbb Z^+_0$ is not closed in $X$, as it's infinite.

Answer (score 1):

Unions of arbitrary elements are not always open, so that sentence doesn't work. What does it mean to be an open set? I think you'll get more mileage out of considering the boundary of a set.